# Show an image on just one dynamically created pages using an 'if statement'

Tags: php, image, layout, dynamic, if-statement

We have several pages generated using PHP on our website with the following titles (for example):

```
http://www.mysite.com/project/category/1
http://www.mysite.com/project/category/2
http://www.mysite.com/project/category/3
```

Each one is created dynamically with the same page layout with each showing a different database result depending on the predefined conditions.

I would like an image to be displayed at the top of the page for just one of the results, let's say for `http://www.mysite.com/project/category/2` - how can I go about this?

The relevant code on our page is this:

```
$category=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from project_category where project_category_id='".$project_category_id."'"));?>
```

If we go down the `if statement` route can you show an example of how to display an example image by modifying the above code to get me started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I opted for an `if statement` (as found here http://www.tizag.com/phpT/if.php).

The original code above was modified in the following way:

```
$category=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from project_category where project_category_id='".$project_category_id."'"));

 if ( $project_category_id == "2" ) {
    echo '<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/imagelink" target="_self"><img src="http://www.mywebsite.com/image.jpg" width="675" height="75" border="0" /></a>';
}?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably make it a property (can be a as simple yes/no) in the database, and use the existing db-result to determine if the category has to display a page. Although this might seem overkill - I'd definitely pick this dynamic solution over a `if ($categoryId == 2) { }` solution any day. Keeps it dynamic and your code clean and generic.

Comment: Just out of interest why would you not the `if ($categoryId == 2) { }` option?

Comment: It keeps your code dynamic - any future categories can show the logo in the blink of an eye. It also keeps your business logic clear, where code with many if exceptions can become really confusing.